# "Try to be on the ball to have a ball"?

Tags: phrases, idiom-meaning

I'd like to know what the following means

> "Try to be on the ball to have a ball"

I know "Have a ball" means is "Enjoy oneself enormously" and "on the ball" means is "to be quick to understand and to react to things", but I can't understand what is the meaning of the two phrases combined.

Comment: Hello, Mohammed. Try looking up '[be] on the ball' and 'have a ball' separately.

Comment: Hello,Thanks dear. I know "Have a ball" means is "Enjoy oneself enormously." and "on the ball" means is "to be quick to understand and to react to things", but i can't understand what does mean combination of two phrases.

Comment: It's combining two idioms.  Look up "on the ball" and "have a ball".

Comment: @MohammadMehrabi, can you provide more context? Where does the sentence come from?

Comment: Yeah i know, so what is the meaning of combination of two idioms? @HotLicks

Comment: @A.P. Unfortunately i can't, My teacher asked it from me to find means of this combined idioms, But i can't understand what is general meaning of it.

Comment: Fulfill the first condition in order to achieve the second.

Comment: @MohammadMehrabi did you see my answer? I've marked some of it in bold. Which part is still unclear and why?

Comment: It is really good answer and example. Thank you dear friend. @A.P.

Comment: You're welcome, Mohammad. Perhaps you need to ask your teacher to provide more context or an example in the future. Language does not function in a vacuum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, it's a play on words using two idioms:

> on the ball: knowledgeable and competent : purposively active : alert

(Webster's Unabridged)

> have a ball: to ​enjoy yourself very much

(http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-a-ball)

The author of the sentence is telling someone **they need to be active, alert, or knowledgeable to enjoy themselves**. It's difficult to be more specific without further context.

Here's a made-up example: A father is teaching his son to play soccer. The son is a goalie. He can't catch the ball because he's not paying attention. He's not enjoying the game very much, so he starts complaining to his dad, at which point the father says: **Try to be on the ball to have a ball, son**. (Meaning: be alert, and you'll have a lot of fun.)